# sklearn f1_score=weighted not matching sample_weight specification

Tags: scikit-learn, weighted-data, f1

I am trying to figure out exactly what this is doing:

```
sklearn.metrics.f1_score(y_pred, y_test, sample_weight=[...])
```

Numerically it simply does not seem to be consistent with whatever the `average='weighted'` parameter is doing.

For example, I have y_test in a Pandas Series. I also put y_pred in a corresponding Series with matching index.

```
counts = y_test.value_counts().sort_index()
weights = 1/counts
f1_score(y_pred, y_test, average='macro') # -> 0.8797748729121277
f1_score(y_pred, y_test, average='weighted') # -> 0.9139386189258313
```

I am not here worried about exactly why those vary, or the degree to which they do.  I understand the idea of weighting the per-label score by its support.  It seems like I **should** be able to get the same answer by manually specifying sample_weights:

```
f1_score(y_pred, y_test, average='macro', 
         sample_weight=y_test.map(counts)) # -> 0.7868154451418584
```

Clearly this is numerically different.  If I assign the sample weights based on y_pred I get a number that is close to, but not identical with, the simple macro averaging.  What's actually happening numerically behind the scenes?

FWIW, prediction_score and recall_score show similar behavior where I cannot get a numeric match between average=weighted and a manual sample_weight.

---

As a secondary question, why is weighting based on support rather than exactly the inverse?! It seems intuitive that getting uncommon targets right should be *more* important rather than less important.  I can do that manually with sample_weight, but I'd really like to understand more accurately exactly what is happening with either.